# After update to Android studio 3.5 getting the following error- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I updated my Android Studio to v3.5 yesterday and I am getting the following error while trying to build a new release build.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> *What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDevRelease'.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: Method com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza Proto VZZ void boolean boolean=Encoded method Method com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza Proto VZZ void boolean boolean and Method com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza Proto VZZ void boolean boolean=Encoded method Method com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza Proto VZZ void boolean boolean

Already referred to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108316/circular-reference-error-in-firebase-with-r8) because before this I was getting the same error for FirebaseInstanceId.

I added the following in my proguard-rules.pro file

`-keep class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { zza(...); }`

`-keep class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseCrash { zza(...); }`

but it did not work for FirebaseCrash class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating Android Studio to 3.5:

1. Update Gradle 5.4.1
2. In Top-Level `build.gradle` update `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'`
3. Add `-allowaccessmodification` to your proguard file.

If you get this warning:
[image]
Add the dependency to force using the latest:

```
implementation "androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0"
```

Comment: I updated the proguard file, forced the latest version of versionedParcelable, re-enabled R8 but the release build is still not being generated with the same error as above.

Comment: These changes (update to 4.3.1, -allowaccessmodification) work for me.

Comment: Worked for me after I removed the FirebaseCrash library implementation from app's gradle file.